# Cannot install Kinect SDK on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have just bought a Kinect v2, and trying to install the SDK so I can use it on Windows 10, but the install is failing every time I try.

It doesn't give an error code it just says install failed and points me to the log files, of which there seem to be six: [Kinect Log Files](https://www.sendspace.com/file/7g4qmj)

I am trying to install the latest version of SDK (KinectSDK-v2.0_1409-Setup.exe).

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: I don't know if it would help but you might want to look at this: https://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/Kinect-with-Visual-Studio-2015-and-Windows-10

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately that link didn't help. But I managed to figure it out anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

In case anyone else has the same issue, here's what I did:

Looking over the log files, I could see that it was the installation of the drivers specifically which was causing the whole thing to fail. It installed the runtime successfully, then the SDK successfully, and then would fail on the drivers and rollback/remove everything.

In the log files it said this:

```
Could not open file C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\kinectsensor.inf_amd64_9d8250c04db77324\kinectsensor.inf. (Error code 0x3: The system cannot find the path specified.)
```

When I looked for that folder, I found one with a different string of letters+numbers after the 'amd64_'. I renamed the folder to the name it was looking for, and then everything worked fine.

I have no idea what this means: why the one I had and the one it was looking for were different, but at least it seemed to install without any issue now!